# Updating value in json object in python

Tags: python, json

I'm struggling with updating a value in a json object.

```
import json

userBoard = '' #see example below. is loaded in a separate function
@app.get("/setItem")
def setItem():
id = request.args.get('itemId')
id = int(id[2:]) # is for instance 2

for item in json.loads(session['userBoard']):
    if item['id'] == id:
        item['solved']='true'
    else:
        print('Nothing found!')        
return('OK')
```

Example of the json:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "t1", "solved": "false"}, {"id": 2, "name": "t2", "solved": "false"}, {"id": 3, "name": "t3"}]
```

However, when I check the printout of the userBoard, the value is still 'false'. Does anyone have any idea? Does this need to be serialized somehow? Tried many things but it didn't work out...

Many thanks!

Comment: `id` in your second line is a python builtin. Your question does not have enough info to properly help you. An example of the json and missing code would help.

Comment: Well… `session['userBoard']` appears to hold a string. You decode that string to an object, iterate over it, update some item in it… and then you discard the entire thing, most certainly you're not writing a string back to `session`…

Comment: @deponovo  just updated the missing code and added an example of the json

Comment: Besides, you never update the global variable `userBoard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could say the question is somehow specific and is lacking some information to provide a simple answer. So I am going to make some assumptions and propose a solution.

First, `id` and `input` are python built-ins and should not be used as variable names. I will use these strings with a `_` prefix on purpose, so that you could still use these names in a safer way.

```
import json
from typing import List

json_ex = '[{"id": 1, "name": "t1", "solved": "false"}, {"id": 2, "name": "t2", "solved": "false"}, {"id": 3, "name": "t3"}]'
_id = 2  # for now a constant for demonstration purposes

def setItem(_input: List[dict]):    
    for item in _input:
        if (this_id := item['id']) == _id:  # requires python 3.8+, otherwise you can simplify this
            item['solved'] = 'true'
            print(f'Updated item id {this_id}')
        else:
            print('Nothing found!')

json_ex_parsed = json.loads(json_ex)  # this is now a list of dictionaries
setItem(json_ex_parsed)

Output:
Nothing found!
Updated item id 2
Nothing found!
```

The contents of `json_ex_parsed` before applying `setItem`:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 't1', 'solved': 'false'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 't2', 'solved': 'false'},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 't3'}]
```

and after:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 't1', 'solved': 'false'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 't2', 'solved': 'true'},  # note here has been updated
 {'id': 3, 'name': 't3'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Moving your code into a separate function has worked! @deponovo